# Filter data to particular user in power bi using RLS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

Suppose I have a column CATEGORY_NAME in table CATEGORY I want a user named abc@xyz.com to see only ('CPU','Storage','Video Card') values of column CATEGORY_NAME in one power bi application.How can I define roles in powerbi desktop for this user.So they can only see these 3 values in CATEGORY_NAME .

How the Table filter dax expression can be written in manage Roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be donne with this code :

```
[CATEGORY_NAME] ="CPU"  || [CATEGORY_NAME] ="Storage"  || [CATEGORY_NAME] ="Video Card"
```